# Meaning of ~てやる

Tags: verbs, て-form, giving-and-receiving

Does ~てやる work the same way as ~てあげる does?

Does ~てやる have any other meanings?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that the other answers have already outlined the main differences between the two. `～てやる` can be much less polite than `～てあげる`, but both have the same basic meaning.

---

In the book [`問題な日本語` by `北{きた}原{はら}保{やす}雄{お}`](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%E3%81%AA%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E2%80%95%E3%81%A9%E3%81%93%E3%81%8C%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%84-%E4%BD%95%E3%81%8C%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%84-%E5%8C%97%E5%8E%9F-%E4%BF%9D%E9%9B%84/dp/4469221686), it's stated that expressions like `猫に[餌]{えさ}をあげる` and `花に水をあげる` have become frequently used even by the older generation in recent times, even though some people have an uncomfortable feeling when they're said.

It says that essentially, `あげる` was the `謙{けん}譲{じょう}語{ご}` ("humble language") of `やる`. As a result, expressions like `先生にあげる` ("give to a teacher") and `友達にあげる` ("give to a friend") have been pointed out as correct, and expressions like `猫に餌をあげる` ("feed a cat") and `花に水をあげる` ("water a flower") have also been pointed out as incorrect by some people. However, due to shifts in the language, people have started using `あげる` in places where `やる` was used, as `やる` has connotations of `品がない` ("lacking style") and `粗野` ("vulgar/rustic/rude") and `あげる` is a `上品な言い方` ("polite/elegant/gracious way of talking").

It also states that `あげる` has lost almost all it's humility and has largely changed from being `謙譲語` into `美{び}化{か}語{ご}`, and that there is major trend to it only being used for people of equal or lower status. As a result, most students can't say things like `これをあげます` and `カバンを持ってあげます` to teachers. It also makes a hypothesis that as `差{さ}し上{あ}げる` has come into more common usage, `差し上げる` might have replaced the `謙譲語` usage of `あげる`.

Answer (score 1):

`~てやる` is synonymous with `~てあげる` but used when the subject of the act (not the person being spoken to) is an inferior. You might define `やる` as "give or do to an inferior".

So "feed the cat" would be `猫にえさをやる`

If your boss told you that your underling needs "a talking to" about something, you might say `私が言ってやります。`

Comment: when you say "give or do" in your definition, you mean it can be a positive thing or a negative thing, right? does this also apply to "ageru"?

Comment: That's difficult to answer. The expression is only as positive or negative as the relationship between the speaker and the subject.

Answer (score 1):

～てやる works the same way ～てあげる does but this is really for inferior ranked people, pets or really close people.

You can use it in the same cases you can use お前. It can be **really** rude if misused so my best advice would be to avoid using it till you feel confortable enough in japanese.