# 許してやる forgiveness?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I was wondering if i said 許してやる it would come across as " i will forgive you" or something else...?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's "I will forgive you", but it's a blunt and arrogant expression that comes with the connotation of "you must be thankful". Here's why: [Meaning of ~てやる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4464/5010)